# Access value in PHP array with unknown dimensions

Tags: php

Consider a multidimensional array with the following structure:

```
[a] => Array
        (
            [b] => Array
                (
                    [c] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => 0
                            [other_value] => 1
                        )

                )

        )
```

I want to access `$array[a][b][c][value]`, but `value` could also be at `$array[a][b][c][d][value]`.

I'm not entirely how to describe what I'm trying to do. I think an alternative explanation would be: I want to access each element in `$array[a][b][c]` but also be able to access each element in `$array[a][b][c][d]`, etc., like using `foreach`, but for an unknown number of nested arrays.

Comment: I can't imagine the situation that you need this kind of array. It could be better if you give us more info about your specific case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`array_walk_recursive()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) could come in handy here.

```
array_walk_recursive($array, function($val, $key) {
    if ($key == "value") {
        // do something
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The task looks like travesrsing a binary tree. Therefore recursion is the easiest way to write a code.

```
$values=array();
function collectValues($array) {
    foreach ($array as $key=>$item) {
        if ($key=="value")
            $values[]=$item;
        else if(is_array($item))
            collectValues($item));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not entirely sure, but this might solve your problem.

```
<?php

function get_next($a)
{
    if(!is_array($a))
        echo $a;
    else
    {
        foreach($a as $b)
            return get_next($b);
    }

}

?>
```

Call the function this way:

```
get_next($your_array);
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like while(is_array($array[x])) $array = $array[x]; $array["value"]...